# Does the equation $\sin(\cos(x))=x$ have a nice closed form solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Does the equation $\sin(\cos(x))=x$ have a nice closed form solution? It is approximately $0.694$.

This is also the value of the limit of $\sin(\cos(\sin(...)))$ iterated over an arbitrary point.

Comment: Since $x=\cos(x)$ does not show analytical solution, I suppose that the answer is no.

Comment: No, but $\sin \sin x=x$ does!

Comment: There is probably a Fourier series solution for the inverse of $x+\sin(\sin(x))$ by integrating $\int_0^\pi e^{i a(t+\sin(\sin(t))}dt$ which can be done with a [Jacobi Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) and [Anger Weber functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=AngerJ%2CWeberE). Then the solution to the equation is simple to get.